# Avoid multiple moves on socket.io multiplayer board game

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am creating a turn-based multiplayer board game with socket.io. If a client moved on the board, I want to disable to move once again, but I can't figure out how to achieve this.

When a client moves, it sends the board state to the server, then the server sends the board state to every connected client. Even to the one who made the move.

This is how I send the board state to the server from the client side:

```
sock.emit("message", board, turn); // Sending the board state to the server
canvas.removeEventListener("click", game);
```

This is how the server gets the updated board state and sends it to every client:

```
  // If we recieve the board state from a client
  sock.on("message", (board, turn) => {
    io.emit("message", board, turn); // Sending the board state to every client who is connected
  });
```

And this how the client code handles when it gets a new board state from the server:

```
sock.on("message", (board, turn) => {
  this.board = board;
  this.turn = turn;
  render(board);

  canvas.addEventListener("click", game);

  setTimeout(function () {
    if (winningMove(board)) {
      // disable click event on both client
      // tell the server that the game ended
      sock.emit("end");
      sock.on("end", () => {
        window.alert("Game Over...");
        window.location.reload();
      });
    }
  }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to send `move` signal to all clients except to the client who made request (move) right ?.

then use `socket.broadcast.emit` for that

```
  // If we recieve the board state from a client
  sock.on("message", (board, turn) => {
    // io.emit("message", board, turn); // Sending the board state to every client who is connected
    socket.broadcast.emit("message", board, turn) // sends to every client except the client who made this request (socket.id).
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `socket.id` value to uniquely identify each connected client (player/board in your case) and add logic on the server side to prevent multiple moves from the same client.

##### Option 1

Keep track of the client that made the last move and ignore any new moves from the same client.
The implementation would look like this:

```js
  // Variable to track last played client
  let lastPlayedClient = null;

  // If we recieve the board state from a client
  sock.on("message", (board, turn) => {
    // Ensure move is made by different client
    if (lastPlayedClient !== sock.id) {
      // Update last played client to current client id
      lastPlayedClient = sock.id;
      io.emit("message", board, turn); // Sending the board state to every client who is connected
    }
  });
```

##### Option 2

On the server side, add logic to identify the client who has to make the next move. Then allow only that client to make the next move. Ignore moves made by any other client.
The implementation would look like this:

```js
  // Variable to track client id of next player
  let nextPlayer = yourLogicToIdentifyNextPlayer();

  // If we recieve the board state from a client
  sock.on("message", (board, turn) => {
    // Ensure move is made by the identified client only
    if (nextPlayer === sock.id) {
      io.emit("message", board, turn); // Sending the board state to every client who is connected
    }
  });
```

---

To improve user experience, you can disable input on the board on the frontend as soon as the first move is made.

Ref: [Socket#id](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-socket-instance/#socketid)